# Python MySqlDB store_result returns only one row

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python

I'm using MySqlDB to execute many queries that I have in a dictionary, my problem is that `store_result()` only returns one of the severals statistics I wan't to get.
Here on of the query that gives me a problem:

```
SELECT value, COUNT(1) \
                FROM ourson_offerattributes oa \
                WHERE attribute_id='status_ltu_indexer' \
                GROUP BY \
                    CASE \
                        WHEN oa.value='OK'                  THEN '0' \
                        WHEN oa.value='ERROR_DOWNLOAD'      THEN '1' \
                        WHEN oa.value='ERROR_LTU'           THEN '2' \
                    ELSE NULL \
                END
```

In my python code I execute it like this:

```
db = sql.connect(**dbParams)
for query in QUERIES:
    db.query(QUERIES[query])
    result = db.store_result().fetch_row(how=1)
```

When I print response I would like to get something like this:

```
({'COUNT(1)': 8932327L, 'value': 'OK'}, 
{'COUNT(1)': 526L, 'value': 'ERROR_DOWNLOAD'}, 
{'COUNT(1)': 14944L, 'value': 'ERROR_LTU'})
```

Instead of that it only give me the first line:

```
({'COUNT(1)': 8932327L, 'value': 'OK'},)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch_row` by default returns a single row. Try with this:

```
result = db.store_result().fetch_row(how=1, maxrows=0)
```